# How can I convert string to double in Java Servlet?

Tags: java, android, string, double

I am passing my latitude and longitude as url parameter to my java servlet. I want to store these latitude and longitude to my mySQL database using hibernate. To convert String to Double I am using following code but its giving me a nullPointerException.

```
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out2.txt");
            req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            String par1 =  req.getParameter("param1");
            String par2 = req.getParameter("param2");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.append(par1);
            out.append("  ");
            out.append(par2);
            double lat=0.0;
            double lon=0.0;
            try
            {
              lat =Double.parseDouble(par1);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
              //not a double
            }
            try
            {
              lon= Double.parseDouble(par2);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
              //not a double
            }
```

I am getting following error in my console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.spark.servlet.PostDataReceiverServlet] in context with path [/HelloServlet] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:991)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at org.spark.servlet.PostDataReceiverServlet.doGet(PostDataReceiverServlet.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:269)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1773)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Code is working fine if I remove both of the parseDouble statements.
@All I am pretty sure either of par1 or par2 is not null. I just checked and I am getting following output in my file. `28.500788  77.395829`. These are the coordinates that I sent from my android app.

Comment: Are you sure `par1` isn't null?

Comment: Im pretty sure that part1 is null since you are getting a NPE when you try to parse it. With that beeing said, your problem lies in your getParameter line

Comment: Yes. Earlier I was writing both of these parameters to a file and it was working fine.

Comment: String par1 =  (String )req.getParameter("param1"); Try this statement and check par1 value and let us know

Comment: No Jimmy, as I commented I was writing these parameters to a file and then manually entering in the database. Now I am using hibernate to do it so I wanted to convert these strings into double first.

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati I just checked as you said, I got this in my file. 28.500788  77.395829

Comment: now you can parse the with no issues. right?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure either par1 or par2 are null.

Modify your code like following snippet.

```
public static double parseDoubleSafely(String str) {
    double result = 0;
    try {
        result = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        //sysout found null
        return 0; 
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //sysout NFE 
        return 0; 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one or both of these two lines doesn't return any value:

```
String par1 = req.getParameter("param1");
String par2 = req.getParameter("param2");
```

Which is why you receive an NPE.

Try:

```
System.out.println("par1 = " + par1 + " and par2 = " + par2);
```

Before you do the type conversion, just to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Is req.getParameter("param1") returning null? Are you passing these parameters?

Check before parsing:

```
if(par1 != null) lat =Double.parseDouble(par1);
if(par2 != null) lon= Double.parseDouble(par2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out like this,

```
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(new File("out2.txt"),true);
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String par1 =  req.getParameter("param1");
        String par2 = req.getParameter("param2");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        out.append(par1);
        out.append("  ");
        out.append(par2);
        double lat=0.0;
        double lon=0.0;
        try
        {
///////////////////////////null Condition chk within Single try///////////

         if ((part1.equals(null)) & (part2.equals(null)))
        {
          lat =Double.parseDouble(par1);
          lon= Double.parseDouble(par2);
        }

///////////////////////////null Condition chk within Single try///////////

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
          System.out.println("One or both of the value is null");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String par1 =  (String) req.getParameter("param1");
 String par2 =  (String) req.getParameter("param2");
```

Make this change and try.